# how can i center an audio signal?

Tags: audio, speech

I'm trying to reconstruct an audio signal, and below is what i got after rescaling.

[image]

How can i obtain centered audio signal such as below?

[image]

---

SOLVED:

ruoho ruotsi's answer addresses my problem :)

i found someone asked the similar question before

[How to remove or filter the drift problem in measured Strain signal?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/27468/how-to-remove-or-filter-the-drift-problem-in-measured-strain-signal)

Comment: Welcome to SE.DSP. You are reconstructing and rescaling a signal using unmentioned processing. They could influence the trend, background or baseline you are observing. Could you please be more specific about your reconstruction?

Comment: I was about to say... ;-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Center" isn't the word that I'd use to describe what you want to do. Your signal does not have a zero-mean, so like @Dole suggested you should use a DC-Blocker (DC-Offset removing) filter to get the job done:

Here are your references:

https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/filters/DC_Blocker.html
https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/filters/DC_Blocker_Frequency_Response.html
https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/filters/DC_Blocker_Software_Implementations.html

the code (from the above links) can be as simple as this, where x is the current sample and y is the filtered sample, while xm1 and ym1 are the x,y from the previous step (i.e. x[i-1], y[i-1]):

```
  y = x - xm1 + 0.995 * ym1;
  xm1 = x;
  ym1 = y;
```

Comment: this is what i was looking for, thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use small High Pass filter. Usually it is suggested to remove the frequencies in the range of 0-200 Hz for speech signals.

Answer (score 0):

Remove DC offset. Either convert to frequency domain and remove bin 0 or just use a very low frequency high pass filter.