# Noisy signal filtering MATLAB

Tags: matlab, denoising

I'm currently working on rectifying a respiratory noisy signal shown below:

[image]

I've already tried to filter the noise as you can see in the image below (full [image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6dMKbuezqN7UTJNOWh6VUlSSXM/view?usp=sharing)):

[image]

The red one is the noisy signal whereas the blue one is the one got after applying the non-linear detrending:

```
dt_ecgl = detrend(ecgl);
opol = 6;
[p,s,mu] = polyfit(t,ecgnl,opol);
f_y = polyval(p,t,[],mu);
dt_ecgnl = ecgnl - f_y;
```

And the green one is the reference signal (correct one) which I'm aiming to have as result of filtering. So my question is how can I acheive a better result? My goal is to have the blue and the green ones conbined (same exact shape) in other words how can I denoise such deformed signal in MATLAB or using any other platform?.

Comment: Have you tried using [a DC blocker?](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/27471/80)

Comment: Look at iirnotch in MATLAB. It is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Use a phase linear low-pass filter, optimize the cutoff frequency, q and slope to be such that you get close as possible to the result.

Note that you aren't really removing the noise per-se, but just the frequencies that contain a lot of noise. If the noise falls withing the bandwidth of the signal, it will be much more difficult to remove.

Comment: You could use frestimate and fit a filter/transfer function onto it.